# How do I print out the relations with linq from table GroupUser

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, relation

I have two tables, one called `Users` and one called `Groups`. I also have one relationship table called `GroupUsers` with PK from Groups and Users.

I can add user 1 with group 2 with:

```
var group = db.Groups.Find(2);
var user = db.Users.Find(1);
group.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But how do I select relations from the `GroupUsers` table? I want to print out all users that belong to a group using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily navigate relationships in Entity Framework using [navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx).

In this case the `Group.Users` and `User.Groups` are navigation properties since **they represent the relationship** between the `Group` and `User` entities.

This example will return all users who belong to the group with primary key value of `1`:

```
db.Groups.Find(1).Users;
```

**See also:**

- [How to: Navigate Relationships Using Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896321.aspx)
- [Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx)